# Not able to select year of birth in standard page layout not in visual force page

Tags: picklist, page-layout, servicecloud, date-field

Not able to select year of birth in standard page layout.

```
        Calendar years don't go back before the following year year -
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a standard page or custom VisualForce page ?

Comment: Custom Object - Standard layout @karthikselva

Answer (score 1):

The problem exists in both standard layout and Visualforce contexts - you can see many years of comments in this idea [Date Field Pop-Up Calendar / Date Picker](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br31AAC).

The simplest solution right now (and the only solution for standard layouts) is to educate your users to first make a selection with the pop-up and then go back and edit the year part in the text field.

If you are using Visualforce and jQuery and are prepared to risk depending on implementation detail that Salesforce does not guarantee to preserve, you can add in more dates using code of this nature:

```
function addYearsToDatePickers() {
    var currentYear = j$('select#calYearPicker > option:first-child').val();
    for (var year = currentYear - 1; year > 1900; year--) {
        j$('<option value="' + year + '">' + year + '</option>').prependTo('select#calYearPicker');
    }
}
j$(document).ready(addYearsToDatePickers);
```

Comment: This will work for visual force page. is the same will work for standard page layout ? i don't think so. @Keith

Comment: @NirmallyaGhosh Correct it will not work for standard layouts. (Most/all of the hacky ways of injecting JavaScript that can modify standard layouts have now been blocked by Salesforce.)